# Prove $4^n > 5*n^2$ where $n\geqslant 3$ is a natural number

Tags: proof-writing, induction

I've got this problem out of an exercise booklet and I'm not too familiar with proofs. It looks like I'm supposed to use induction, so far I have:

Solving a base case, where $n=3$

So,

$4^3 > 5\cdot3^2$

$64 > 45$

So, that is okay. Next, I assume $n = k$ and that there must exist a $k + 1$, so:

$4^{(k+1)} > 5(k+1)^2$

I expanded this out:

$4 \cdot 4^k > 5k^2+10k+5$

And now I'm stuck. What should my objective be? Could someone break this up into something digestible?

Answer (score 1):

If $4^k>5\cdot k^2$  we need to show $4^{k+1}>5\cdot(k+1)^2$

We have $4^{k+1}>5\cdot4k^2$

So, it is sufficient to show $4k^2>(k+1)^2\iff 4>\left(1+\frac1k\right)^2$

Observe that $\left(1+\frac1{k+1}\right)^2<\left(1+\frac1k\right)^2$

and $\left(1+\frac1k\right)^2<4$ for $k=2$

$\displaystyle \implies\left(1+\frac1k\right)^2<4$ for $k\ge2$

Answer (score 0):

Your induction hypothesis is $4^k > 5k^2$. This leads to
$$4^{k+1} = 4 \cdot 4^k > 4 \cdot 5 k^2 > 5 k^2 + 2 \cdot 5k^2 + 5k^2 > 5k^2 + 10 k + 5.$$
The last inequality is valid for all $k \ge 2$.

Comment: I'm a little lost - are those inequalities chained together or do they lead into each other?

Answer (score 0):

You want to show that $4\cdot 4^k>5k^2+10k+5$ if you already know that $4^k>5k^2$ and $k\ge 3$.

Note that $k> 2$ implies $5k^2>10k$ and of course $5k^2>5$. So we quickly find that
$$4^{k+1}=4\cdot 4^k>4^k+4^k+4^k> 5k^2+5k^2+5k^2 > 5k^2+10k+5=5(k+1)^2$$
as was to be shown. The first inequality follows by simply dropping a summand, the second by appying the induction hypothesis, the third by the mini-inequalities just shown.

Comment: Sorry - how do all those chained >'s work? Is it legal to write a proof as such?

Comment: Yes, it's not only legal, but correct. We reserve the Math Police Department for serious violations, like dividing by zero. @user99868